# How to use formulae in alternate column in google sheet?

Tags: excel

```
    A       B            C      D            E    
1   Total   Penetration  Value  Penetration  Value      
2   300000  0.001        300    0.0015       450
3   300000  0.001        300    0.0015       450
```

How can we drag the formulae across the row with an alternate column?

```
C2 = B2*$A2
AND 
E2 = D2*$A2
```

I want to drag this formula across the row 1, in alternate column and each column uses the previous column value and fixed value from A2.

Answer (score 0):

Just have to select the two column, B and C and then we have to drag to the entire  row.